# Git: Re merging or rebasing on top of several dependent branches

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-rebase, feature-branch

I often find myself developing a feature branch which depends on the two or more (mutually unrelated) branches forked from the same commit. My commit tree usually looks like this:

```
o -- o  master
|\
| o -- B  feature-1
|       \
|        o -- A  my-branch
 \      /
  o -- C  feature-2
```

or

```
o -- o master
|\
| o -- B  feature-1
|\ 
| o -- B -- o -- C -- A  my-branch
 \
  o -- C  feature-2
```

Now, suppose more commits on each dependent branch occur, with the latest being `B'` and `C'`, respectively.
If I do the default merge now, I will get something like:

```
o -- o  master
|\
| o -- B -- o -- B' feature-1
|       \         \
|        o -- A -- o  my-branch
 \      /         /
  o -- C -- o -- C'  feature-2
```

However, I would like something like:

```
o -- o  master
|\
| o -- B -- o -- B'  feature-1
|                 \
|                  o -- A  my-branch
 \                /
  o -- C -- o -- C'  feature-2
```

or

```
o -- o  master
|\
| o -- B  feature-1
|\
| o -- o -- B -- o -- B' -- o -- C -- o -- C' -- A  my-branch
 \
  o -- C  feature-2
```

I am looking for a quick and non-interactive way (except conflict-resolution) of achieving this, since I'm faced with this scenario on a regular basis.

What would be the least painful / most convenient way?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, please clarify what are branches and what are commits in your examples. Also please clarify what commands you are usually using to get the results in the examples.